# how to encrypt username and password in laravel login blade

Tags: laravel-5.8, burp

I have created laravel application. I have found an issue when i get burp-suite report.I need to encrypt email and password (vulnerable to cross site request forgery attack)

This is my burp-suite report.

> Cookie:
>   XSRF-TOKEN="";
>   my_new_session=""
>   _token=eff13b445f30f3f0527e58625b44c085&email=admin%40test.com&password=123456

login.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <script>
          window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
                'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
            ]); ?>
        </script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
         <input type="email" autocorrect="off"  autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" class="form- 
           control" placeholder="Username" id="email" name="email" 
           value="{{ old('email') }}" maxlength="20" >
        <input type="password" autocorrect="off"  autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" 
           name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" 
           id="password" value="{{ old('password') }}" >
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
     </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Inside your controller method

```
$email = Hash::make($request->input('email'));
$pass = Hash::make($request->input('passwor'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't really encrypt your emails but passwords you do.
Encrypt passwords in your controller when the user has submitted a registration form.
And run the code below:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; // Include this at the top

$password = Hash::make($request->password);
```